# How to insert shadow over a slider

Tags: jquery, css, caroufredsel

I created a slider with car images using carouFredSel plugin. Now I want to add shadow over the first and last item and I hope someone will give me the answer.

So far this is what I have:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

Every element is using this code:

```
<li style="width: 170px;">
                <a href="astra-brandpage" onmouseover="mouseOverCar(this, 'Astra')" onmouseout="mouseOutCar(this, 'Astra')">
                    <img src="~/Astra.png">
                    <b>Astra </b>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Just target the right and left arrow by giving background color with shadow

Comment: Using `box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 5px black` should give the desired effect, but the shadow would match the aspect ratio of the entire container element. I am not sure how to skew the shadow, but this could be a starting point. (So for the image you have above, the inner area clear of the shadow would be elliptical instead of circular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sauhard Gupta, `box-shadow: inset` helped me